# Symfony 3 - FosUserBundle - Redirect to the current page after registration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a registration modal window, I would like after a successful registration to redirect the user on the same page.

For that, I override the `fos_user_registration_confirmed` route with a new associated controller containing a `Request` object.

In my form action field, I try to add a parameter `current_path` containing the current path and then retrieve it with `$current_path = $request->attributes->get('current_path');`, but it's always NULL.

I try the same thing with a form hidden parameter and retrieve it with `$current_path = $request->request->get('current_path');`, but again it's always NULL.

The current path in the form is correct, but it seems that I cannot retrieve it in my controller.

```
public function registrationConfirmedAction(Request $request)
{
    // POST: doesn't work
    $current_path = $request->request->get('current_path');

    // GET: doesn't work
    if($current_path == NULL)
        $current_path = $request->attributes->get('current_path');

    if($current_path != NULL)
        return new RedirectResponse($current_path);

    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('pp_home_homepage'));
}
```

**Edited**: how I get the current path

The current_path is in my register_content.html.twig template:

```
{% set current_path = app.request.get('current_path') %}
```

I add it at two places in the code:

```
{{ form_start(form, {
    'method': 'post',
    'action': path('fos_user_registration_register') ~ '?current_path=' ~ current_path,
    'attr': {
        'class': 'fos_user_registration_register',
        'novalidate': 'novalidate',
    }
}) }}
```

And here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_path" value="{{ current_path }}">
```

The attribute is generated in my base template:

```
{% set current_path = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) %}
```

Then I send it to my controller:

```
{{ render(controller(
    'PPUserBundle:Registration:register',
    {'current_path': current_path}
)) }}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you added the current url

Comment: @Chibuzo Edited. But, as I said before the `current_path` value is valid, there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I fixed that in the `regiserAction` method. I retrieve the current path before testing if the form is submitted :

    $current_path = $request->request->get('current_path');

Then I changed `return $response;` in  the `if ($form->isValid())` block to :

    return new RedirectResponse($current_path);</del>

**Edited**: use listener

I found out that it's better to create a listener implementing `EventSubscriberInterface` :

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess'
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
{
    $current_path = $event->getRequest()->request->get('current_path');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($current_path . '?registration_confirmed=true');
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Then don't forget modify `app/config/services.yml` :

```
pp_user.registration_success:
    class: PP\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationSuccess
    autowire: true
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```